# How to move tables (ending with some suffix) from one database to another in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to move some tables from one database to another, I know it is easy for a single table, I have already used the following command for this and it works perfect:

```
alter table my_old_db.mytable rename my_new_db.mytable
```

but now the scenario is different, I have to move all those tables to new database which ends with "_mp".

Comment: you can do server side  ... using a select for get the table name you  need  and then based on these name create the sql command you need  and run all this command in a loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a   way to do this was via an external file. This is my implimentation :

```
 function changeSchema($oldName, $newName, $type, $len)
{
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_mp'  AND 
        TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name'");
    if($res){
        while($line=mysql_fetch_object($res)){
             mysql_query("ALTER TABLE db1.$line->TABLE_NAME rename db2.$line->TABLE_NAME");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, but would querying `information_schema.TABLES` be a better option?

Comment: You also have some incorrect quotes in your `SELECT` query

Comment: @Phil Thanks Its my typo mistake...
:)

Comment: thanks for your help, but there was a typo in your select query, you were using = before LIKE statement, it should be 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_mp'
not
WHERE TABLE_NAME = LIKE '%_mp'

Comment: i have tried this, it is returning me all the tables when i tried to print table names in while loop, but didn't move the tables to new database, seems your ALTER query didn't work, can you please check

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in one statement. There's no support for wildcards in the RENAME TABLE or ALTER TABLE statements.

At least [RENAME TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html) can rename multiple tables in one statement, but only by specifying fixed table names. So you can generate a RENAME TABLE statement that moves all your tables in one pass:

```
SELECT CONCAT('RENAME TABLE ',
   GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('my_old_db.`', TABLE_NAME, '` TO my_new_db.`', TABLE_NAME, '`')),
   ';') AS _sql
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='my_old_db' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%\_mp';
```